# Change datepicker mindate if its a friday

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using a jquery UI datepicker to select their delivery day - the minimum delivery date is 2 working days from the current day... all that is working fine.

The issue is if the current day is Friday, we want the earliest day they can select to be Tuesday.

In short terms - if the current day is friday, the mindate needs to be +4, if its Saturday +3.

Here's the code.

Thanks!

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("#date").datepicker( { 
     beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
     minDate: +2, 
     maxDate: "+2M"
   } );
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var min=2;

switch (new Date().getDay()) {
    case 5:
       min = 4;
       break;
    case 6:
       min = 3;
       break;
}

jQuery(function() {
 jQuery("#date").datepicker( { 
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    minDate: min, 
    maxDate: "+2M"
   } );
});
```

Comment: So far seems to work like a charm - thanks! I'm going to mark as correct even thought I have to wait for a few days to test thoroughly, but it looks right to me.

Comment: your welcome, you can test changing the case values it will always deliver 2 unless its friday(5) or sat (6)